# How do I fill a grid row using Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, zurb-foundation

I want to acheive the following layout,

```
Desktop:
[----A---][-B-]
[-C-][-D-][-E-]

Mobile:
[----- A -----]
[---B--][--C--]
[---D--][--E--]
```

I can get 'B' to jump down to a new row in the mobile version and take up half the space, but I can't get it to share with 'C' - here is what happens:

```
[----- A -----]
       [---B--]
[--C--][---D--]
       [---E--]
```

How can I acheive the desired layout? I am using Zurb Foundation 4 framework.

The markup is  as follows

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    B
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    E
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as far as I see you can use following markup for your purpose ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJnJd/)):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 small-12 columns">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
    E
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't realised that the `div`s would 'wrap'.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in one `.row`.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q3xn/).